# Enumeration versus array

Tags: c++, arrays, enums

I was wondering what would be better:
An enumeration declaration or a string array:

```
enum MonthName{January, February, March, April, May, June, ...)
```

or

```
string MonthName[12] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", ...)
```

because to me it doesn't seem like it matters.

This variable will only be accessed by one function, to display month based on the number input.

Comment: If it's displaying it, the string array would be better. You can't convert the name of an enum item to a string automatically.

Comment: Which is better, a car or a pizza? These do two completely different things.

Comment: @PeteBecker that's easy... pizza.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you want to use it.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - no, you can sell the car and gets lots of pizza.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Depends on the car and on the pizza. :) http://pizza.com/news/worlds-most-expensive-pizza

Comment: aah, good one. My confusion I guess lies in the fact I didn't realize you cant print the enumeration values. So, that's that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to display the *name* of the month, an `enum` won't do you any good at all.  The identifiers in an enumeration type definition are visible only to the compiler; you can't print them at run time.

You need the array of strings (or perhaps an array of `const char*`s).

The names of the months are also available via the standard library, using the `strftime()` function declared in `<ctime>` (from the C standard library's `<time.h>` header). Getting the month name for a given month number using `strftime()` is not straightforward (you'd have to build a `struct tm` object first). It does have the advantage of using month names for the current locale rather than being hardwired to English.

And don't forget that array indices start at 0; December is at index 11, not 12.

Answer (score 1):

It matters a great deal. If you need printable text, use the array of strings. Enumerations don't translate into readable names; they're just integral values.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in common between enum and array.
With the enum you cannot print the name of the month, this is just an integer...

In your case you should use

```
static const char* MonthName[2] = {"January", "February", ...};
```

Comment: @BenVoigt: Is that valid in C++? Looks more like C# to me.

Comment: @Keith: oops, I answer questions about both, got mixed up.  I think it was the use of `string` (as opposed to `std::string`).

Answer (score 0):

Both enum and strings are different in this case and will produce different results. In case of enum you can store month number with month name in a variable of enum type e.g.

```
MonthName mn = March;
```

The variable `mn` will carry integer value `2`.
In case of array of strings with month names you need to specify month number as array index and what you'll get is the string name of the month rather the month number e.g.

```
string mn = MonthName[2];
```

The variable `mn` will carry the string `"March"` and can be used to display month.
However, you can use both enum and string array in a better way e.g.

```
string mn = MonthName[March];
```

Here, enum `March` will act as index of the string array `MonthName` and returns the `"March"`.

Comment: Don't name a variable `__mn`. Names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved to the implementation. So are names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know it but unintentionally used it here. Will keep it for future...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend combining the two, using a table of `structs`:

```
enum Months
{
    JANUARY = 1,
    FEBRUARY,
    APRIL,
//...
    DECEMBER,
    NUMBER_OF_MONTHS
};

struct Month_Enum_Conversion_Entry
{
    Months                month_id;
    char const * const    month_name;
};

Month_Enum_Conversion_Entry month_conversion_table[] =
{
    {JANUARY, "January"},
    {FEBRUARY, "February"},
//...
    {DECEMBER, "December"}
};
static const unsigned int NUM_TABLE_ENTRIES =
    sizeof(month_conversion_table) / sizeof(month_conversion_table[0]);
```

To convert an enum to text, search the table for the enum and access the text field:

```
std::string Month_ID_To_Name(Months m)
{
    char const * p_month_name = NULL;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < NUM_TABLE_ENTRIES; ++i)
    {
        if (month_conversion_table[i].month_id == m)
        {
            p_month_name = month_conversion_table[i].month_name;
            break;
        }
    }
    return std::string(p_month_name);
}
```

Two optimizations:

1. Load table into a `std::map` for faster conversion.
2. Add a null, unused entry in the conversion table before January and
   then index into the table using the month number.  The above method
   is more robust than indexing into an array, as the array has an
   implied relationship between index and value.  The above example
   provides an explicit relationship between ID and name.